# Overlapping Flare canvas in Flex, how to clip it to the container?

Tags: apache-flex, layout, actionscript, prefuse, flare

I'm having a serious issue when trying to display a FlareCanvas within my application. It simply doesn't respect the bounds ([see image here](http://postimage.org/image/35exab8ro/))

I've tried "clipContent" and a bunch of alternatives but nothing seems to prevent the canvas of being "passing" over its container. What should I do? It is taking me several weeks!

In Flex main.mxml:

```
<flexvis:FlareCanvas id="graph" width="800" height="600" verticalScrollPolicy="on" clipContent="true" horizontalScrollPolicy="on"  />
```

The full class FlareCanvas which FCACanvas extends is in: https://github.com/prefuse/Flare/blob/master/flare/src-flex-integration/flare/flex/vis/FlareCanvas.as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the code used for FlareCanvas isn't exactly the best.  If I were you, I'd just wrap the FlareCanvas into another container that would clip the contents to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I actually changed the FlareCanvas by the FlareVisualization class in the same package and it worked out.